# Capturing all the text until the next occurrence including the line breaks in regex (Python 3.x)

Tags: python-3.x, regex, regex-lookarounds, python-re

I have a `.tex` file and I am looking to prepare standalone documents from that for each question. In nutshell, I need the question and their choices in the following format at the end.

```
[
    {'question': 
        {'text' : 'If $\vec A = t^2 \vec i -t \vec j + (2t +1)\vec k$, what is  $\dfrac{dA}{dt}$?',
        'marks': 2
        },
     'choices': [{'text': '$2t\vec i -  \vec j + 2\vec k$', 'is_correct': True }, {'text': '$2t\vec i +  \vec j + 2\vec k$', 'is_correct': False, ...}]
    },
...]
```

I using `python 3.x` to write regular expressions to search and do the job. The following is a minimal example

```
 \documentclass{exam} 
  
  
  \begin{questions}
  
  \question[2] If $\vec A = t^2 \vec i -t \vec j + (2t +1)\vec k$, what is  $\dfrac{dA}{dt}$?
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{choices} 
    \correctchoice   $2t\vec i -  \vec j + 2\vec k$
  
    \choice  $2t\vec i +  \vec j + 2\vec k$
  
    \choice  $t\vec i -  \vec j + 2\vec k$
  
    \choice  None of these
   
    \end{choices}
  \end{multicols}
      
  \question[2] Is $\nabla \phi $ is perpendicular
   to the surface $\phi(x,y,z) = c$ where $c$ is a constant?
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{choices} 
    \choice  Not all the times
  
    \correctchoice   Yes, Always
  
    \choice  No, Never
  
    \choice  None of these
   
    \end{choices}
  \end{multicols}
      
  
      
  \end{questions}
  \end{document}
```

I am struct at writing regular expressions and splitting the questions separately with its choices. I have tried the following:

```
import re

with open('qpaper.tex', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    regex = re.compile(r"\\question.*")
    qns = regex.findall(content)
    for q in qns:
        print(q)
```

This gives only the text after `\question` but until the linebreak. In my case, I needed it until the next occurrence of the `\question`.

**Note**:
In my case, all my question papers will have the exact same format, and all the questions will be insdide `\begin{questions}...\end{questions}`, if there is any other better way to achieve this, that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
(?s)\\question.*?(?=\\question|\Z)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/djsquQ/1)

This expression extracts substrings starting with `\question` up to the next closest `\question` or end of string (`\Z`).

EXPLANATION:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?s)                     set flags for this block (with . matching
                           \n) (case-sensitive) (with ^ and $
                           matching normally) (matching whitespace
                           and # normally)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  question                 'question'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character (0 or more times (matching
                           the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    question                 'question'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \Z                       the end of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: Thats awesome.. Works like a charm.. Thanks. I think, I can use the similar regex to achieve my goal.